# Why 'echo $(cat /path/to/fileName)' list my files and directions?

Tags: command-line, echo

When I printout the content of a file with `echo $(cat /path/to/filename)`, it list my files and directions too. But when I do with `printf "$(cat /path/to/filename)\n"` it works fine.

I tried also saving it into a variable `content='cat /path/to/filename'` (also `content=$(cat /path/to/filename`) and then print by `echo $content`, but I getting the same result (list files and directions).

**I want to store the content of the file into variable and pass the variable into my script as an input to next command.**

Note that the content of my file has special character `*` in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because after performing command substitution, the shell perform word splitting (or field splitting) on the result if you don't quote them.

POSIX defined [word expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) as:

> The order of word expansion shall be as follows:
>
> 1. Tilde expansion (see Tilde Expansion), parameter expansion (see Parameter Expansion), command substitution (see Command Substitution),
>      and arithmetic expansion (see Arithmetic Expansion) shall be
>      performed, beginning to end. See item 5 in Token Recognition.
> 2. **Field splitting (see Field Splitting) shall be performed on the portions of the fields generated by step 1, unless IFS is null**.
> 3. Pathname expansion (see Pathname Expansion) shall be performed, unless set -f is in effect.
> 4. Quote removal (see Quote Removal) shall always be performed last.

In your case, `*` matched all thing in current working directory. You must quote the result to get the expected output:

```
echo "$(cat /path/to/fileName)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Quote it:

```
$ echo "*" >> test
$ echo $(cat test)
bash43-001 bash43-002 bash43-003 bash43-004 bash43-005 test
$ echo "$(cat test)"
*
```

As a first rule, always quote command substitution.

The bare `*` will get expanded in `bash`, unless you turn off globbing (`set -f` or `setopt noglob`) or quote/escape it: `"*" \*`. For command output, it's always best to use quoting.